# Connecting to sql database with powershell gives an error: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-administration

I am able to connect using SSMS.
However, when I try to connect via PowerShell it give me an error:

```
$connString = "Data Source=server;Database=mydb;User ID=myusern;Password=mypass"

#Create a SQL connection object
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString

    #Attempt to open the connection
    $conn.Open()
    if($conn.State -eq "Open")
    {
        # We have a successful connection here
        # Notify of successful connection
        Write-Host "Test connection successful"
        $conn.Close()
    }
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 
'username'."
At line:7 char:5
+     $conn.Open()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Common issues: trying to use SQL Login authentication with a Windows username and password; Password is incorrect; The "mydb" database doesn't exist; The "myusern" login doesn't have access granted to the "mydb" database.

Comment: See Aaron's [fantastic](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456) troubleshooting to login problems.